# Synaptic package Manager Broken packages

Tags: synaptic

How to remove broken packages using synaptic package manager 
i already isntalled it but after selecting status it is not showing broken packages options it is only showing installed, installed (manual) not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Broken packages that was not shown on synaptic are viewed and purged through the terminal,

If you want to view the broken packages,then run this command

```
dpkg -l | grep ^rc | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

If you want to remove the broken packages,then run this

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep ^rc | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Comment: tried first command but it's not showing any broken packages :(

Comment: then you have no broken packages.